# Dudas sobre las mitigaciones a la vulnerabilidad de la librería Log4j de Apache

Tags: apache, apache2, log4j, log4j2

El pasado 9 de diciembre de 2021 se dio a conocer una vulnerabilidad crítica relacionada con la librería Log4j de Apache. [Aquí se detalla la vulnerabilidad](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2021-44228). En ese link se mencionan posibles mitigaciones. Espero puedan echarme una mano con las siguientes preguntas (me disculpo de antemano por si mis preguntas suenan demasiado triviales):

**Mitigación 1:** *set the system property log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups or the environment variable LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS to true*. Esto está compuesto de 2 operaciones distintas:

1. La primera es establecer la propiedad del sistema log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups a TRUE. ¿Cuáles son y dónde están las propiedades del sistema?
2. O bien, establecer la variable de entorno LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS a TRUE. En apariencia esto es tan fácil como ejecutar esto: `export LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS=true`. ¿Hay algún problema con crear esa variable de entorno en un sistema que no usa la librería Log4j?

**Mitigación 2:** *all PatternLayout patterns can be modified to specify the message converter as %m{nolookups} instead of just %m*. Es decir, que en lugar de utilizar `%m`, hay que usar `%m{nolookups}`, y que esto se hace en todos los patrones PatternLayout. [En este lugar](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) se listan los posibles archivos de configuración de la librería Log4j. Logré encontrar este /usr/lib/appdynamics-php5/proxy/conf/logging/log4j2.xml, el cual contiene múltiples líneas como esta: `<PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{DATE} %5p %c - %m%n"/>`. Supongo que es justo en esos archivos de configuración donde hay que ejecutar esta mitigación, y no en otro lugar, ¿correcto?

**Mitigación 3:** *remove the JndiLookup class from the classpath. For example: zip -q -d log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class*. No encuentro en ningún lado un archivo llamado JndiLookup.class. Supongo que si no existe, no hay que buscar nada más y esta posible mitigación no aplica, ¿correcto?

Comment: [***¿Cuáles son y dónde están las propiedades del sistema?***](https://www.techiedelight.com/difference-between-system-properties-environment-variables-java/) - - - ***¿Hay algún problema con crear esa variable de entorno en un sistema que no usa la librería Log4j?*** si no usas Log4J, ¿para qué te preocupas? - - - ***y no en otro lugar ¿cierto?*** si claramente dices que sólo allí lo has encontrado, ¿en qué otro lugar puede ser? - - - ***Supongo que si no existe, no hay que buscar nada más*** esa suposición es claramente correcta.

Comment: Todo depende de la versión de Log4j: `log4j-core-<version>.jar`. Por lo que tienes que buscar archivos `log4j-core-*.jar` y dependiendo de la versión aplicas la mitigación.

Comment: Porque querrias mitigar tu sistema, en lugar de securizar el mismo para que no pueda ser atacado? no es solamente la libreria la que esta mal, esta mal tambien el sistema donde esta contenido. En este caso, en tus sistemas, en que parte estas usando dichas librerias? porque no migraste ya a los parches implementados? Las mitigaciones son del momento.. ya hay parches para solucionar esto (y los mismos no solucionan todo, asi que abra nuevos parches)....